# Monitoring Azure Blob container file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I have a blob container in which I receive XML files. This container gets empty once the files are processed by function app. Is it possible to set up an alert (via email) if those files didn’t processed within 24hours? That is, if still files are remaining after 24hours ( may be with file name and size). What is simplest way to do it?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the portal go to Monitor -> Storage Accounts and select the account you want to monitor. Then select "capacity" and click the value on "Blob capacity". Open the Storage Capacity graphic in the metrics explorer. Select only "Blob Capacity" as metric and click "New Alert rule". Here you can add a condition and an action group (email).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think there's anything available natively in Azure to do this. You will need to implement something of your own.

One possible way would be to write a `Timer Triggered Azure Function` which will get invoked once a day and lists all blobs in the blob container you want to monitor. It will then filter out the blobs created before certain date/time value (more than 24 hours ago in your case). You would then generate an email with the name/size of these blobs and send that email.

Same can also be achieved through `Logic Apps` as well I believe.